# How pointer reference works in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I have 3 pointers:

```
Node* head;
Node* temp=head;
Node* p=new Node(2);
```

Now I assign:

```
temp->next=p
```

Will the next of head will also be changed?

```
head->next=?
```

Comment: No `next` of `head` will **not** be changed when we write `temp->next=p;`. It can change but for that you have to tell us more about how your data structure actually looks like. So the real answer is, "it can/cannot change depending on what structure you have". If anyone tells you, yes or no with 100% guarantee he/she would be lying since the question is incomplete as it doesn't give any information about how the `Node` looks like.

Comment: Yes, if `head` would actually point at some allocated memory, `temp` would point to the same memory.

Comment: If `head` pointed at a `Node` object, `temp` would point at the same `Node` object. Modifying that object through either pointer modifies that object.

Comment: @JasonLiam I don't follow your argumentation. `head` and `temp` point at the same memory no matter how the structure looks like. `head->next` and `temp->next` are the same thing so any assignment to `temp->next` will change `head->temp`. 100% guarantee.

Comment: The keyword you should search for is **[aliasing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing_(computing)#Aliased_pointers)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if `head` would actually point at some allocated memory, `temp` would point to the same memory.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Node {
    Node(int X) : x(X) {}
    int x;
    Node* next;
};

int main() {
    Node* head = new Node(1);

    Node* temp = head;                     // temp points to the same memory as head

    Node* p = new Node(2);
    temp->next = p;                        // head->next is the same as temp->next

    std::cout << head->next->x << '\n'     // prints 2

    delete head;
    delete p;
}
```